# Does discriminator converge to probability 0.5 in GAN just for the output of generator?

Tags: generative-models, gan

We know that in GANs, discriminator converges to 0.5. I want to become sure that the following statement is true:

Discriminator converges to 0.5 for the examples generated by generator and for the real examples; but for the examples that are not as good as the real instances, the discriminator is sure that it is a fake example. In other words, for real instances or instances generated by the trained generator $P_D(x)=0.5$; but for samples that are a little deviated from the true distribution $P_D(x)=1$.

This is because after training the GAN, both generator and discriminator are good, so the discriminator is really good at detecting out-of-distribution samples.

Answer (score 0):

For samples that are a little deviated, this does not indicate that they are completely fake. Imagine seeing a face you've never seen before and deciding that it's absolutely, without a doubt, not a face (also think uncanny valley - looks like a face but might not be a face). Both you and a discriminator that generalized well will output probabilities that are slightly higher than 0.5, but not 1. A discriminator that overfits on the data, however, may actually output 1 though.